# Last_seen function on telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Hello guys i've been working on a Telegram script for few days now and im facing my last issue before i can pull this script up.
my correct problem is im checking by defualt on the first time that the scripts run if the target is online.
now I want the script to check if the user isnt online when was the last time hes been seen online, which is basically doable with events but the thing with events is that they work only if they get triggered by an event and I want the last seen check to be done automatically on the begging of the script.

```py
first_msg = False
def first_con():
    global first_msg
    if first_msg == False:
        if target_details.user.status != "UserStatusOnline":
            print(f"{target} is correctly Offline.")
            last_seen = "x"
            print(f"{target} Was last seen at : {last_seen}")
            target_file = open(f"{target}_log.txt", "a")
            print(f"{target} Was Offline at {datetime.now()} \n", file=target_file)
            print(f"{target} Was last seen at : {last_seen} \n", file=target_file)
            target_file.close()
            first_msg = True
        else:
            print(f"{target} is correctly Online. \n")
            target_file = open(f"{target}_log.txt", "a")
            print(f"{target} Was Online at {datetime.now()} \n", file=target_file)
            target_file.close()            
            first_msg = True
    else:
        print("Error while checking correct status. \n")
        errors_log = open("errors_log.txt", "a")
        print(f"{datetime.now()}: Something went wrong checking correct status. \n", file=errors_log)
        errors_log.close()
```

Comment: Checking if a value is a instance of a type is done with [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), not comparing to a string like `"UserStatusOnline"`.

Comment: `target_details = client(GetFullUserRequest(target))`                                                       and `target_entity = await client.get_entity(target)`                            is the same thing only thing the entity requires await and the GetFull doesnt.

Comment: Both require `await`, and the first one is more expensive than the second one for certain inputs.